# Stopping arithmetico-geometric sentence

Tags: python

I have a function `u_terme` that computes values of the sequence `3u + 1`.  I would like a stop function reached(M) that returns the lowest `u` value at which a given functional value is reached.

However, my code below doesn't work: it exits immediately and prints a single `0`.  Help?

```
def u_terme(x):
    i = 0
    u = 0
    while i < x:
        u = (3 * u) + 1
        i = i + 1
    print(u)


def reached(M):
    x = 0
    f = 0
    while f >= M:
        f = u_terme(x)
        x = x + 1
    print(x)
```

Comment: What's your question? Is something not working?

Comment: You should first note that you never actually return x in the reached function.

Comment: You probably want `while f < M` based on your description. (Not `while f >= M`.)

Comment: Add a `break`? It's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: And `u_terme` should `return u` at the bottom.

Comment: `f` starts off `<M` so your `while` loop is never entered. Flip the conditional probably.

Answer (score 1):

**ANALYSIS**:

`u_terme` fails to return any value.

`reached` exits immediately: your `while` loop quits as soon as `f < M`.
You have that logic reversed: you want to continue while f <= M.

Also, please use meaningful variable names.

**REPAIR**:

Make `u_term` return the computed value:

```
def u_terme(x):
    u = 0
    for i in range(x):
        u = 3*u + 1
        # print x, u
    return u
```

Make `reached` iterate properly and return its result:

```
def reached(limit):
    val = 0
    func_val = 0
    while func_val < limit:
        val += 1
        func_val = u_terme(val)
        print val, func_val
    return val


print reached(50)
```

Output:

```
1 1
2 4
3 13
4 40
5 121
5
```

Output:

```
17
```

Comment: @smarx: Since the original code doesn't work, the "repair" code should *not* work the same.  :-)  However, let me try to reinterpret the `uterme` code and update this answer ... I think I see your point: it's not a simple linear equation.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. However, the u_terme is giving the value of u(1) = 3 * u(0) + 1 et cetera, which makes it impossible for me to reduce it, I think

Comment: It seems that this code from Prune is working for every answer (I tried until a value 3500 and it returns the right value)

Comment: @smarx: Thanks for the catch.  My comment 34 minutes (7 comments) ago is there to document that change.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the question is so unclear that it is difficult to provide a definitive answer. For example, what are allowable values of M?

At the first look, however, it is obvious that your u_terme() function has no return value (well, that is, it always return None). This means that f in the reached() function after the first iteration will be None and the loop will terminate.

Comment: Yes, I figured the conditional was wrong, thank you very much. I'm quite new at Python and I didn't think about putting "return u" which seems obvious now. M could be any value, and reached(M) should return the value of x when u_terme is over M.

Comment: As @smarx mentioned in a comment to a different answer, your condition in the while-loop is also suspicious.

Answer (score 0):

Just because back-in-forth in comments doesn't work to well, I think this is the correct simplified, more efficient version of the code:

```
def u_terme(u):
    return (3 * u) + 1

def reached(M):
    x = 0
    u = 0
    while u < M:
        u = u_terme(u)
        x += 1
    return x

print(reached(50))  # 5
```

**EDIT**

To help with the confusion in the comments. This new `u_terme` doesn't do what the previous one did. The previous one took a number `x` and computed `u` `x` times. This new one just returns the next value based on the previous one. This avoids duplicate work.

This code shows how to use it to get the expected values:

```
def u_terme(u):
    return (3 * u) + 1

u = 0
for i in range(5):
    print(i, u)
    u = u_terme(u)

# Output:
# 0 0
# 1 1
# 2 4
# 3 13
# 4 40
```

**EDIT 2**

Just for fun, here's another way to do this. Why this is correct is an exercise left to the reader. :-)

```
def reached(M):
    u = 0
    x = 0
    while u < M:
        u += 3**x
        x += 1
    return x
```

Comment: The value of x for M = 50 is 5, so it should be right. Thanks so much for your help

Comment: Okay, great! The original code is a little confusing on this point... it tends to return 1 more than you really want. (It returns an `x + 1` for the `x` that generates the value reaching `M`.)

Comment: What I don't understand is how reached(M) gives the right results whereas u_terme(u) on its own doesn't. u_terme(u) gives for consecutive results (1, 4, 7, 13) while I'm expecting (1, 4, 13, 40)

Comment: Yes it does absolutely.

Comment: @Batiste Check out my latest edit for another interesting (to me, anyway) solution.